Complex functions and inner product $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} , g\rangle $
I'm working through this academic paper : stability of the soljutions of differential equations whose author is Bernard Beauzamy. A link to paper
In the academic paper, it work with the next norm
\begin{equation*}
 \left\Vert f\right\Vert= \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 r dr\frac{d\theta}{\pi} \right)^{1/2}
 \end{equation*}
for analytic polynomials
and the scalar product associated is
\begin{equation*}
  \langle f,g\rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2}f(re^{i\theta})\overline{g(re^{i\theta})} r dr\frac{d\theta}{\pi}
 \end{equation*}
The lemma that i'm trying to check say the following
For any f,g and $\mathcal{P}_2$
\begin{equation*}
   \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} , g\rangle =\langle f, zg \rangle \qquad \langle zf,g \rangle =\langle f, \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \rangle
 \end{equation*}
the functions  f  and  g  are given by
\begin{equation*}
 f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j z^j, \quad g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j z^j.
 \end{equation*}
The derivative of f with respect to z is
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j j z^{j-1}.
 \end{equation*}
so the scalar product is
\begin{align*}
 \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}, g \rangle &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j j (re^{i\theta})^{j-1}\right) \overline{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k (re^{i\theta})^k\right)} r \, dr \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi} \\
 &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_j j r^{j-1} e^{i(j-1)\theta} \overline{b_k} r^k e^{-ik\theta} r \, dr \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi} \\
 &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_j \overline{b_k} j r^{j+k} e^{i(j-k-1)\theta} r \, dr \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi}.
 \end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i(j-k-1)\theta} \frac{d\theta}{\pi} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } j = k+1, \\
0 & \text{if } j \neq k+1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}, g \rangle &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} (k+1) r^{2k+3} r \, dr \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} (k+1) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{2k+3} dr.
\end{align*}
The other scalar product is
\begin{align*}
\langle f, zg \rangle &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (re^{i\theta})^j\right) \overline{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k r^{k+1} e^{i(k+1)\theta}\right)} r \, dr \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_j \overline{b_k} r^{j+k+1} e^{i(j-k-1)\theta} r \, dr \, \frac{d\theta}{\pi}.
\end{align*}
Again, integrating over $ \theta $ and j=k+1
\begin{align*}
\langle f, zg \rangle &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} r^{2k+3} r \, dr \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{2k+3} dr.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}, g \rangle &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} (k+1) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{2k+3} dr, \\
\langle f, zg \rangle &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \overline{b_k} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{2k+3} dr.
\end{align*}
These are not equal due to the factor (k+1) present in $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}, g \rangle $. So i don't know where is the fail.

Actually, you can prove this lemma in an easier and more straightforward way by coming back to complex cartesian coordinates through the change of variable $z = re^{i\theta}$. As a consequence, the inner product can be rewritten as follows :
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_\Bbb{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}\; e^{-|z|^2}f(z)\overline{g(z)}
$$
Now, given that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(e^{-|z|^2}f\bar{g}\right) = e^{-|z|^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\bar{g} - \bar{z}e^{-|z|^2}f\bar{g},
$$
one has thus in the present case :
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z},g \right\rangle
   &= \int_\Bbb{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}\; e^{-|z|^2}\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z}\overline{g(z)} \\
   &= \int_\Bbb{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}\; \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(e^{-|z|^2}f(z)\overline{g(z)}\right) + \bar{z}e^{-|z|^2}f(z)\overline{g(z)}\right) \\
   &= -\int_{\partial\Bbb{C}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}}{2\pi i}\; e^{-|z|^2}f(z)\overline{g(z)} + \int_\Bbb{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}\; e^{-|z|^2}f(z)\overline{zg(z)} \\
   &= \langle f,zg \rangle
\end{align}
$$
where we used Stokes' theorem and assumed that the boundary integral over the contour $\partial\Bbb{C}$ (which might be interpreted as a circle with infinite radius on the complex plane) vanishes for suitable $f$ and $g$.
In conclusion, the adjoint of the complex derivative (with respect to the inner product defined above) is given by the multiplication operator, i.e. $\partial_z^\dagger = z$.

Thanks for the reply. You are using the differential form and therefore Stokes' generalized theorem. I have been reading  Wikipedia and other sites and I have not been able to find information to understand what you are doing. Would you mind giving me a bibliographical reference or some link where this theorem is explained?

Here the correct solutions. The first case $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} , g \rangle$. Change of variable
\begin{align*}
  u   =r^2 \\ 
   \qquad du  =2r dr 
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 (k+1)\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2}r^{2k+1}dr=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u}u^{k +1/2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{k}du = (k+1)\frac{\Gamma\left((k+1)/1\right)}{2}=(k+1)\frac{\Gamma (k+1)}{2}=\frac{(k+1)!}{2}
 \end{align*}
The second case $\langle f, zg \rangle $. The same change of variables
\begin{align*}
 (k+1)\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2}r^{2k+3}dr=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u}u^{k +3/2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{k+1}du = \frac{\Gamma\left((k+2)/1\right)}{2}=\frac{\Gamma (k+2)}{2}=\frac{(k+1)!}{2}
 \end{align*}
Hence, the inner products are equals.
(In the last equality i used the gauss integral and its relation with Gamma function. Look at in Wikipedia)
